# Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator in Singly Linked List

Tags: c++, linked-list, copy-constructor, assignment-operator

This is sort of a follow up to the question I asked yesterday on my assignment with singly linked lists. I've been struggling with creating the copy constructor, leaving the assignment operator until last because I think they're somewhat similar to implement. I think I have the steps down for creating the copy constructor:

1. Create a new node with the new list as a parameter.
2. Traverse through the list, adding each node from list1 to list2 (I have an add function which I think would help with this?)
3. Increment through list2 while doing so, so each node gets properly added.

Please correct me on any steps (or maybe I need to expand on the steps). I've looked at a lot of code found on Google in an attempt to understand what I have to do, but my implementation and understanding must still be fuzzy. Here is the code I have (the un-commented code is my last attempt. The commented code is what I've tried before, hoping that I'm at least on the right track) so far:

```
template<typename T>
SLList<T>::SLList(const SLList<T> & lst2) : head() {
    cout << "Calling copy constructor..." << endl;
    for (Node *ptr = lst2.head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        add(ptr->data);
    }
}
```

Edit: Thank you WhozCraig for helping me with the copy constructor above.

And here is the `add` function, just in case it could be used:

```
template<typename T>
void SLList<T>::add(const T& val) {
    Node *prev = head; 
    for (Node *ptr = head->next; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
        prev = ptr;
        if (ptr->data == val) {
            return;
        }
    }
    prev->next = new Node(val);
}
```

What I'm thinking may be wrong, though is in line 5 of the first code snippet I have `lst2.add(ptr->data);` would it call the `add` function and just replace `ptr->data` with `val`? Just wondering if writing the line like that wouldn't bring up any errors.

Edit: I forgot to post this code snippet as well. It shows me creating the two integer lists and attempting to make `iList2 = iList;` so that the copy constructor is called. I think I may have done it wrong, though.

```
void intList() {
    SLList<int> iList;
    cout << "\nNow showing integer list..." << endl;
    iList.add(5);
    iList.add(6);
    iList.add(6);
    iList.add(3);
    iList.add(4);
    SLList<int> iList2 = iList;
    iList.print();
    iList2.print();
}
```

Edit 2: The copy constructor issue was fixed above, but now when the `add` function gets called, it crashes on the `for` loop. Could it be because `lst2` is a `const` object and `add` is not a `const` function, as WhozCraig said?

Edit 3: My attempt at assignment operator, just in case:

```
template<typename T>
const SLList<T>& SLList<T>::operator=(const SLList & rhs) {
    cout << "\nCalling assignment operator..." << endl;
    // Step (1) Delete the existing list
    while (head != NULL) {
        Node *temp = head;
        head = head->next;
        delete temp;
    }
    // Step (2) Build a new, copy list
    if (this != &rhs) {
        for (const Node *ptr = rhs.head; ptr != NULL; ptr = ptr->next) {
            add(ptr->data);
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: What about you use `std::list` or `std::forward_list` instead?

Comment: I forgot to mention this was an assignment and I believe we have to solve it just by assigning and reassigning pointers. Not sure if those two would be allowed.

Comment: You're adding in the wrong direction. The parameter of the copy constructor is the *source*, not the *target*. "The object" (this) is the target, not the source. That `lst2.add` call should be `add`, and the loop should be going over `lst2.head`. As written this stands no chance of even *compiling*, let alone correctly running because `add` is not a `const` function and `lst2` is a const object.

Comment: @WhozCraig Oh.. So `for(Node *ptr = head;` should be `for(Node *ptr = lst2.head;`? Would I also have to change the `ptr = ptr->next` to `ptr = lst2->next` as well?